# default vaules on datetime filter in filter grid telerik in mvc- js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

Hello i want to put defaul values in the filters type date in my grid filter of telerik, i attached an image, please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaCKY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question to include your code, and also to list out what you have tried already and what doesn't work.

I'm going to take a *guess* though that you're using a Kendo DatePicker from the image you posted, and show one way that you can use to set the value.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("datepicker")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
    )

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
        datepicker.value("10/10/2000");
    });
</script>
```

More information on this code example [can be found here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/datepicker/api).